# Optional product sale through paypal IPN

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-ipn

Consider the following scenario

A users comes to page "A"(acting as notify_url) after making payment from Paypal for purchase of product 1. On "A" user is shown another product. If user does not want this product 2 he gets redirected to page b and his login credentials are created for product 1. However if they want to buy product 2 they are redirected to the paypal where they make the payment of product 2 and are then redirected to page "B" where users credentials are created for both product 1 and product 2.

I am using C# with .net framework 3.5. Is this scenario possible?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it's possible, but notify_url is for IPN.  Don't confuse that with PDT, which is what you'd be using to send data back to the return URL that you send users to after they complete payment.

On your return URL you can display any extra options you want and send them through payment again if necessary.  You might want to look into references transactions, too, as that would allow you to charge the second payment without making the user go back through the PayPal pages again.